# Android: wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() returns TRUE but WiFi is disabled

Tags: android, wifi

Here, a Tablet with Android 4.0.

```
wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
```

returns `true` but if I look at Android default Wifi settings, Wifi is still Off...

How can I check if WiFi is on without using `isWifiEnabled()`?

Comment: what is funny is that isWifiEnabled returns `getWifiState() == WIFI_STATE_ENABLED;`

Comment: If you are testing wifi right after changing its state, then the result of isWifiEnabled() is wrong. I had this issue, tried to place a pause and then test it, then it worked. Say, after 5 seconds. The point is that it takes a few second to propagate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use `getWifiState()`
Gets the Wi-Fi enabled state.
Returns:
One of `WIFI_STATE_DISABLED`, `WIFI_STATE_DISABLING`, `WIFI_STATE_ENABLED`, `WIFI_STATE_ENABLING`, `WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN`

Comment: Intresting situation, i will try to undertand it. I write to you if i found some answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code.

```
SupplicantState supState; 
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
supState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
```

**Which will return one of these states at the time you call getSupplicantState();**

```
ASSOCIATED - Association completed.

ASSOCIATING - Trying to associate with an access point.

COMPLETED - All authentication completed.

DISCONNECTED - This state indicates that client is not associated, but is likely to start looking for an access point.

DORMANT - An Android-added state that is reported when a client issues an explicit DISCONNECT command.

FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE - WPA 4-Way Key Handshake in progress.

GROUP_HANDSHAKE - WPA Group Key Handshake in progress.

INACTIVE - Inactive state.

INVALID - A pseudo-state that should normally never be seen. SCANNING - Scanning for a network.

UNINITIALIZED - No connection.
```

Comment: Actually supState is UNINITIALIZED and isWifiEnabled()=TRUE... is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Settings.Global.WIFI_ON

```
public boolean isWiFiSettingOn() {
        boolean isOn = false;
        try {
            isOn = Settings.Global.getInt(mContentResolver, Settings.Global.WIFI_ON) != 0;
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // This should never happen
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't retrieve status of Settings.Global.WIFI_ON - returning the default value FALSE")`enter code here`;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isWiFiSettingOn? - " + isOn);
        return isOn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ConnectivityManager cm =    (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
    State wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
```

And check wifi.states....

Answer (score 0):

You also have to check that you have the permission for that in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```